# If Select query returns no rows, execute insert query in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i had this query that checks if a schedule is already assigned before assigning to another person. The problem is, the first query executes very well, but if SELECT query returns no rows, the INSERT query which is the next query should execute.

This is the sample code;

```
Private Sub DisplayConflictSchedTIMEROOM()
        Dim strConn As String = My.Settings.SLCBRegistrarDBConnectionString
        Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConn)
        Try
            sqlCon.Open()
            Dim QUERY As String
            QUERY = "SELECT ListofSubjects.[Course No.], ListofSubjects.[Descriptive Title], CSchedSubTD.TimeAndDay, UtlyRoom.RoomName, CSchedSubInstructor.NameInit, CSchedSubSect.Section " &
                    "FROM CSchedMAIN INNER JOIN CSchedClass ON CSchedMAIN.SubjCode = CSchedClass.id INNER JOIN ListofSubjects ON CSchedClass.Subj = ListofSubjects.SubjectID INNER JOIN SemesterList ON CSchedMAIN.SemID = SemesterList.SemID INNER JOIN SchoolYear ON CSchedMAIN.SYID = SchoolYear.[SY ID] INNER JOIN CSchedSubTD ON CSchedMAIN.TDCode = CSchedSubTD.TDCode INNER JOIN UtlyRoom ON CSchedMAIN.RoomID = UtlyRoom.RoomID INNER JOIN CSchedSubSect ON CSchedMAIN.Section = CSchedSubSect.id INNER JOIN CSchedSubInstructor ON CSchedMAIN.InstID = CSchedSubInstructor.EmpID " &
                    "WHERE (CSchedSubTD.TimeAndDay = '" & cmbtimeday.Text & "') AND  (UtlyRoom.RoomName = '" & cmbRoom.Text & "') AND  (SchoolYear.[School Year] = '" & cmbSY.Text & "') AND (SemesterList.Description = '" & cmbSemester.Text & "')"
            CMD = New SqlCommand(QUERY, sqlCon)
            Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader
            While Reader.Read
                If Reader.HasRows Then
                    ConflictMessagebox.ShowDialog()
                Else
                   INSERTSched()
                End If
            End While
            sqlCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub INSERTSched()
        Dim strConn As String = My.Settings.SLCBRegistrarDBConnectionString
        Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConn)
        Try
            CMD = New SqlCommand
            CMD.Connection = sqlCon
            CMD.CommandText = "InsertClassSched"
            CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            'Post your class schedule
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", cmbCOURSE.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", txtSection.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", cmbDepartment.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseNo", CMBCourseNo.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescTitle", cmbDescription.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeDay", cmbtimeday.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Room", cmbRoom.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Instructor", cmbInst.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Semester", cmbSemester.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SY", cmbSY.Text)
            sqlCon.Open()
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch sqlex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(sqlex.Message)
        End Try
        sqlCon.Close()
        ClassSchedule()
    End Sub
```

Please help!

Comment: Your If Else is inside your While Reader.Read loop.  If there are no rows, the if then block will never be entered.

Comment: Thank bro.. you've just saved my ass! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is a bit flawed.  You call `Read` on the `SqlDataReader`, and then check to see if it has rows.  If there are no rows in the reader, the loop will not be executed and the If Then block will never be entered.

Change the logic to simply check if the reader has rows or not, and it should work:

```
If Reader.HasRows Then
    ConflictMessageBox.ShowDialog()
Else
    INSERTSched()
End If
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim. you've just saved my ass. Thanks a lot!